# Animate CSS Pseudo Class

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a search icon that transforms into an input when hovered over. I am using the pseudo class `::after` for the handle of the magnifying glass. Essentially, I want the handle to smoothly disappear when the icon is hovered over. Here is a link to my [codepen](https://codepen.io/Hudson_Taylor11/pen/NRKpAv?editors=1100).

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}
#magnifying-glass {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 14px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  transition: 1s;
}
#magnifying-glass::after {
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 85px;
  left: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
input {
  display: none;
  border: none;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#magnifying-glass:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
#magnifying-glass:hover #magnifying-glass::after {
  width: 0px;
}
#magnifying-glass:hover input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="magnifying-glass">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: If the Answers provided help, feel free to tick the check mark to mark as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to smoothly disappear and not so sharp change the transition times below to the following.

```
#magnifying-glass::after {
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  width: 14px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 88px;
  left: 100px;
  -webkit-transition: 2.5s;
  -moz-transition: 2.5s;
  -o-transition: 2.5s;
  transition: 2.5s;
}
```

And to make it even smoother you can add:

```
#magnifying-glass:hover::after {
   transform: rotate(360deg);
   height: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Heres a codepen with these changes. https://codepen.io/Ballard/pen/EgYLKG

Comment: @Jerad Thanks for the edit, I missed that bit out :)

Comment: Hey! No Problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add an `opacity: 0` to hover state

```
#magnifying-glass:hover::after {
   transform: rotate(360deg);
   height: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/2691pjod/3/

---

## Snippet

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #fff;
}
#magnifying-glass {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: 14px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  transition: 1s;
}
#magnifying-glass::after {
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  width: 14px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 85px;
  left: 50px;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  -moz-transition: 1s;
  -o-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
}
input {
  display: none;
  border: none;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 40px;
}
input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
#magnifying-glass:hover {
   width: 300px;
}
#magnifying-glass:hover::after {
   transform: rotate(360deg);
   height: 0;
   opacity: 0;
}
#magnifying-glass:hover input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="magnifying-glass">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

Comment: Just wondering why you have alot of unneeded code in there? As in the keyframes, they don't appear to have any benefit on what he is doing

Comment: What do you mean by unneeded code? I have provided an example what it does and why it's needed.

Comment: well the keyframes doesn't add any benefit to the animation, he wants a smoother animation unless i have misread, the transition time and opacity is what will make it smoother and you only need to add opacity in one place

Comment: Agreed! Thanks for the tip. I did that previously but for some reason it didn't work as expected. that's why I used `@keyframes`. Will correct the answer. And also upvoting yours over mine. But better provide an example in yours. :)

Comment: I just added a codepen, I cant however appear to get the handle to appear back from the location it disappears, It defaults at the center on reappearing

Comment: I too noticed that. But will see how OP actually wants it. As of now the answer already provides what he wants. :)